# What mechanism does Java use so that it does not allow reasignment of an array reference to another with a bigger type?

Tags: java

From a book I've been reading, it said

```
int[] splats;
int[] dats = new int[4];
char[] letters = new char[5];
splats = dats;     //ok
splats = letters;   //not ok
```

What is the mechanism that it does not allow such an assignment?

**Edit**:

As opposed to this assignment where

```
int[] weightList = new int[5];
byte b = 4;
char c = 'c';
short s = 7;
weightList[0] = b;   //ok
weightList[1] = c;   //ok
weightList[2] = s;   //ok
```

this is allowed. 

**Edit :** 
I think I understand how widening and narrowing work but in my head

```
new int[4];
and
new char[4];
```

are two array objects in the heap with the type of 'array'. Aren't they ? 
Perhaps like

```
new List<int>
and 
new List<char>
```

Sure their individual element types are different but the List objects themselves 
are of the same List type.
I read that arrays of objects are allowed to perform that operation as long as 
the assigning side has a narrower type(subclass).
So maybe I could think of this like

> Because the primitive type char does not inherit the primitive type
>   int, you cannot reassign an array of chars into an array of ints ?

well of course, one primitive type "extending" another doesn't sound right but just
to make it easier to understand.

Comment: The compiler checks the type, whether similar or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'mechanism' is type safety.

- A reference to `char[]` is not the same type as a reference to `int[]`
- There is no inheritance-relationship between them
- There is no specified widening conversion rule

So the assignment is illegal.

Comment: I've been thinking about your answer and then it hit me. Thanks ! : )

Comment: Could I say that the above operation is not allowed because "char[] does not pass the IS-A(n) int[] test" ?

Comment: Ok, I'll save it for another time : )

Answer (score 2):

The compiler checks the types. An array of primitives can only be assigned to another array of primitives with the same type.

Comment: Arrays of *any* type, not just primitives.

Answer (score 1):

```
splats = dats;     //ok
```

There `splats` is holding a referecne to an array of `int` type, **regardless of the size/length**. It can hold the reference to other array  but only of `int` type.

```
splats = letters;
```

In the above line, types are different, so it can't be assigned.

For your edit:

```
weightList[0] = b;   //ok
```

since `weightList` is of type int and it **can accomodate** `char`, `byte` and `short` data type because `int` is 32 bit, where as `byte` is 8 bits and `short`  and `char` is 16 bit.

You should see: [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - int to long, float, or double
> - long to float or double
> - float to double
>
> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

```
weightList[0] = b;   //ok because its byte
weightList[1] = c;   //ok because it converts to ASCII 
weightList[2] = s;   //ok Directly store , because its short
```

Yes, These can easily mapped into the int array. Because individually the values are inserted into the index (0,1,2) those values must be less than capacity of int data type.The size and length matter ,when type casting. That may be upper bound or lower bound.[Read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

Answer (score 1):

You asked about Java mechanism. In this short example java uses Widening Primitive Conversion and Narrowing Primitive Conversion. To understand more clearly? you can read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java allows assignment of an array reference only when the types of the arrays themselves are *identical*, not when the element types are *merely* assignment compatible.  This is referred to as having "invariant" arrays.

This has nothing to do with the *length* of the array, but rather the *type*.

And this is not affected by whether the elements can be individually assigned particular values by having the values silently widened.

Answer (score 0):

For arrays apply the same rules as for any other type of variable. If the array is of the same type or derived from it you can assign it, otherwise not.

For Example:

```
 JComponent[] a = null;
 JTextField[] b = null;
 a = b;   <- OK, because JTextfield is derived from JComponent.
 b = a;   <- error because JComponent is NOT derived from JTextField
```

It doesn't matter if this is an array or not, because only the type matters:

```
 JComponent a = null;
 JTextField b = null;
 a = b;   <- OK, because JTextfield is derived from JComponent.
 b = a;   <- error because JComponent is NOT derived from JTextField
```

In your case, char and int are unrelated to each other, so they can not be assigned.